# Android: How to determine the Length of text (in pixels)?

Tags: android, fonts, textview, width, pixel

I am building an app and based on the content and screen size I want to dynamically set the font size to fill the entire screen.

Is there a way to determine the width of a line of text (in pixels)? I want to avoid the flicker that trial and error can present the user. Can it be done without first displaying a TextView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Paint class has a measureText method for this purpose :)

Comment: Interesting. It is amazing how methods like that seem to hide in plain site. :-)    I will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: units aren't matching up when it comes to setting the width of a view.  edit: seems to work if the text isn't too long, text upwards of 2000 characters is giving me WAY higher number than expected.

Comment: Since a text is meant to be placed into a view with specific font size etc., the `view.paint` should be used instead of a plain new instance.